# Disable Gateway Timeout for Specific Nginx Port / Folder

Tags: nginx, php-fpm, fastcgi, timeout

How can I disable the nginx timeout when accessing through a specific port, or simply a specified folder. Whichever is easier.

Basically I have some scripts which need to execute for a long period of time and the gateway timeout is preventing them from completing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two directives involved here, one at nginx `fastcgi_read_timeout` as described [here](https://serverfault.com/questions/386107/disable-fastcgi-read-timeout-in-nginx), the other is at php-fpm.conf `reqest_terminate_timeout`, you can set this to 0 to disable timeout.

At nginx set `fastcgi_read_timeout` to any arbitrary large value as answered in my first link, you can set this inside any specific `location`.

Answer (score 2):

Normally if you have scripts that need more time there are a few solution.

1. You can increase the `fastcgi_read_timeout` and `reqest_terminate_timeout`. But the problem is you shouldn't set the value too high. If you have a lot of processes that blocks each other they are open for a long time and its possible that your server can't deliver your content anymore.
2. What i prefer is don't execute long running scripts over your Webserver. Use the command line and run your script with a cron for example. Normally a Webserver is not a very good way to execute long running scripts.

I had the same problem before a few month we have changed to php-cgi and had a script which was running over wget. I have changed the script that it was running with a CLI.